# Short sci-fi book about aliens coming to Earth and challenging humans to a game

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I'm looking for a sci-fi book. It is a small book, about the palm of a hand, and has fewer pages, about 17. It was part of a short series of sci-fi books just like it.

The only two things I remember about this book is that the front cover had this orange and green chess game and the story was about aliens coming to Earth and challenging humans to a game.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Whe you say "*this orange and green Chess game*", do you literally mean that picture?

Comment: Interstellar Pig by William Sleator? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiH9sL2-7P9AhVRY8AKHU2WA0gQFnoECCEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FInterstellar_Pig&usg=AOvVaw15Y0LDviOi0g_3qfksmFsi

Comment: Typical! I've been on here for nine years and I still can't do an image, new kid does it in the first posting. Haha

Comment: To LogicDictates, hi, from what I remember, it had that 90s or 2000s look and as for when I read it, I read it in high school back in 2015